# Rerendering fields in VF Page based off radio input

Tags: visualforce

I had this working to some extent months ago, so I know it can be done well, but since revisiting after some changes, it doesn't work and I'm stumped.

I have contacts on a certain account. In this visualforce page, if there is a contact, you have the option to update existing contact (radio button 1, default), or to create a new contact (option 2).

By default, it shows the information (first name, last name, phone, etc) in the fields with "Update Existing Contact" selected. When I click on "Create New Contact", I want those fields to clear for entry of the new information. This much had worked in the past.

In my visual force page, I have the following:

```
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Billing Primary Contact" collapsible="false" columns="2" id="PrimaryContactBlock">

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

                <apex:selectRadio value="{!createOrUpdatePA}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!createOrUpdate}" rerender="PrimaryContactBlock"/>
                    <apex:selectOption rendered="{!hasAccountContact=true}" itemLabel="Update Existing Contact" itemValue="Update Existing Contact">
                    </apex:selectOption>
                    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Create New Contact"  itemValue="Create New Contact">
                        <apex:actionSupport action="{!createOrUpdate}" rerender="PrimaryContactBlock"/>
                    </apex:selectOption>

                </apex:selectRadio>


            </apex:pageBlockSection>


            <!-- renders if UPDATING Contact -->
```

```
            <apex:inputField value="{!accountContactItem.FirstName}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Update Existing Contact'}" tabOrderHint="24"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!accountContactItem.Phone}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Update Existing Contact'}" tabOrderHint="25"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!accountContactItem.LastName}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Update Existing Contact'}" tabOrderHint="28"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!accountContactItem.MobilePhone}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Update Existing Contact'}" tabOrderHint="29"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!accountContactItem.Title}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Update Existing Contact'}" tabOrderHint="26"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!accountContactItem.Fax}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Update Existing Contact'}" tabOrderHint="30"/>
            <apex:inputField label="Contact Role (on Site)" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Update Existing Contact'}" value="{!accountContactRoleItem.Role}" tabOrderHint="27"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!accountContactItem.Email}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Update Existing Contact'}" tabOrderHint="31"/>

            <!-- renders if CREATING NEW Contact -->

            <apex:inputField value="{!newPAContact.FirstName}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Create New Contact'}" tabOrderHint="24"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!newPAContact.Phone}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Create New Contact'}" tabOrderHint="28"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!newPAContact.LastName}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Create New Contact'}" tabOrderHint="25"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!newPAContact.MobilePhone}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Create New Contact'}" tabOrderHint="29"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!newPAContact.Title}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Create New Contact'}" tabOrderHint="26"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!newPAContact.Fax}" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Create New Contact'}" tabOrderHint="30"/>
            <apex:inputField label="Contact Role (on Site)" rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Create New Contact'}" value="{!accountContactRoleItem.Role}" tabOrderHint="27"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!newPAContact.Email}" rendered="{!newPAContact ='Create New Contact'}" tabOrderHint="31"/>



        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

And this is a function in the controller:

```
    public void createOrUpdate(){
    System.debug('THE STATUS IS : ');
    System.debug(createOrUpdateSite);
    if(createOrUpdateSite == 'Create New Contact'){
        newSiteContact = new Contact();
        newSiteContact.LastName = 'Insert Name';
        siteContactRoleItem.IsPrimary = true;
    }
    if (createOrUpdatePA == 'Create New Contact'){
        newPAContact = new Contact();
    }


}
```

I had something else before that was more convoluted, so that's what I'm starting with and I'm wondering what to do to progress...right now, nothing happens apparently when I click the Create New radio option...

Answer (score 2):

Single equals is for `assignment`, you need to use double equals to for `condition`.

For example in your page, change rendered condition:

```
rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA ='Create New Contact'}"
```

To:

```
rendered="{!createOrUpdatePA == 'Create New Contact'}"
```

In all the rendered condition.

Why not include all `inputfield`'s inside single block section and add rendered condition to block instead of component level?

Comment: It still does not clear out/rerender the fields

Comment: Maybe can you update your question with modified code.

Comment: All I did was add the ==